# Dynamic Asset URL in Einstein Content Selection

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am looking for a solution to dynamically adjust the Asset URL in Einstein Content Selection. I have multi-language in the shop and work with locales. How do I get the locales for ECS dynamically integrated?

Example

[www.myshop.com/**fr-fr**/category](http://www.myshop.com/**fr-fr**/category)
[www.myshop.com/**es-es**/category](http://www.myshop.com/**es-es**/category)

Comment: Basically your Webshop has do to do the dynamic stuff. Just think of it like you have a prefix Url that is determined by your Webshop code and you only have to add the suffix to make it work. The dynamic part is inside the coding of the Webshop

Comment: I upload the assets for ECS in a CSV and can set a URL per asset. I don't want to have a row in the CSV for each language version. I am looking for a way to dynamize this asset URL. E.g. with Ampscript. The locale for each store is stored in the master DE, with which I sync the consumer profiles in the ECS settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the Parameter Manager? See under step 2.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_pb_add_an_asset.htm&type=5

Comment: That's what the SF support told me. Think that's the info that I need. If Parameter Manager does not work, here's another solution: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347478/how-can-you-add-ampscript-to-an-asset-url-in-einstein-content-selection